# How do I highlight complete line in a RichTextbox in a C# form

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, highlight

After browsing a .txt file I stored each line in an array (i.e. filetext)...

```
String[] filetext = File.ReadAllLines(filepath);
```

How can i highlight particular lines with a color and show them in RichTextBox?

Comment: was my answer any helpful for you?

Comment: @stefankmitph - Yes, Thank for your help...I have one more question..If i find a text in richtextbox i want to highlight whole line..So, what is the syntax for this case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a simple method (in your forms code):

```
private void ShowText(string[] text)
{
    richTextBox1.Clear();
    richTextBox1.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, text);
}
```

and given a line number/index:

```
private void HighlightLine(int lineIdx)
{
    richTextBox1.Select(richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(lineIdx), richTextBox1.Lines[lineIdx].Length);
    richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution with the help of above code.

There is no need to store each line in an array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ptrsize; i++)
{  
richTextBox1.Select(richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(linenum[i]),richTextBox1.Lines[linenum[i]].Length);
richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
}
```